# Creating a table.png from lists

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following

- list: `var = [n, x ,Y, y, E]`;
- where: `n`, `x`, `Y`, `y`, `E` are lists of same length;

How can I output the information within the `var` into an image table such that the information for `n` is displayed in one column?

I'm trying to use this table within latex so exporting in any other format is welcomed. I tried in csv but the information was badly displayed in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a small example using `csv` module with `;` as delimiter so Excel opens it properly by default.

I have defined 3 lists of equal length, and built a list of those lists.

The trick is to transpose the lines as columns using `zip` and the `*` operator to expand arguments as the sublists, so `zip` interleaves each element of each sub-list, building a new tuple.

Then just call `csv.writer.writerows` on the resulting iterator to get data in columns.

The code:

```
import csv

n=list(range(1,10))
X=list(range(11,20))
E=list(range(21,30))

l = [n,X,E]

with open("foo.csv","w",newline="") as f:
# with open("foo.csv","wb") as f:  # use this instead for legacy Python 2.x
    cr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    cr.writerows(zip(*l))
```

result (as text):

```
1;11;21
2;12;22
3;13;23
4;14;24
5;15;25
6;16;26
7;17;27
8;18;28
9;19;29
```

Open it in excel, you'll get 3 neat columns.

EDIT: if, following your comment, you have floating point numbers and you want to limit the number of digits, replace the `csv.writerows` line by:

```
cr.writerows((["{:.3}".format(float(x)) for x in row] for row in zip(*l)))
```

(each data is converted to `float` and displayed with 3 decimal digits)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have only one question. my x is of the form [0.0, 0.2, 0,4....]. However, in the csv file i get 0.40000000000000002. Do you know how I can correct this?

Comment: the default float to string conversion does that. see my edit.